# Добавить margin-left 20px если браузер mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Нужно для определенного класса, добавить margin-left если открыт в браузере Mozilla Firefox
Я пишут так:

```
    var sBrowser, sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;

if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
    sBrowser = "Mozilla Firefox";
    $(".prof-moz-margin-left").css("margin-left") = "20px";
}
```

если пишу alert() в условие, он срабатывает, а вот css не подставляется

Comment: $(".prof-moz-margin-left").css({"margin-left":"20px"})

Comment: @Tchort вроде бы времена, когда надо определять браузер, чтобы каждому из них подкидывать свои стили, уже прошли. Вы уверены, что это надо делать?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko да, нашел выход из ситуации, указал в стилях 1.8em, все браузеры съели